# How to set Mongodb Field Naming Strategy in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring boot 1.3.1.Release with Spring Data Mongodb and want to setup field naming strategy for fields. Below is my application.properties file:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test
spring.data.mongodb.field-naming-strategy=org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.SnakeCaseFieldNamingStrategy
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
```

Everything is working fine except the field naming strategy. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? Are you getting any error/exception ?

Comment: Did you get any error? If so, paste the error.

Comment: It is not throwing any error/exception and the field name is not getting changed. e.g. In Java class if the field name is firstName, it should change to first_name in Mongodb. That's not happening.

Comment: @ahmadimt - Have you got any idea , to make it work ?

Comment: @smilyface sorry for late response. I just tested with the latest version of Spring Boot. It is working for me. we need to define the following property in our ```application.properties```

``spring.data.mongodb.field-naming-strategy=org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SnakeCaseFieldNamingStrategy``

Comment: @ahmadimt - Thank you for the reply. I dig in the spring code and find out the exact code what they expect :) Did in java itself (I mean, adding in properties like above was not working for me)

Answer (score 1):

SpringBoot 1.3 has spring-data-mongodb version 1.8 and in this version of jar class with name **SnakeCaseFieldNamingStrategy** is not present.

Checked with the api docs here..
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/api/

I guess u need to degrade the version of spring-data-mongodb to 1.5 or so. Probably this is the reason your Field naming strategy is not working.