# How to custmize FieldNamingStrategy in spring-data-mongo

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

In spring-data-mongo ,is this interface's function still can be extended?

What I want is saving CamelCaseToUnderline in mongodb and querying UnderlineToCamelCase.

I see the part source code, it has a final FieldNamingStrategy.if I wanna costomized it ,it must before instantiation, how?

```
public class BasicMongoPersistentProperty extends AnnotationBasedPersistentProperty<MongoPersistentProperty> implements MongoPersistentProperty {
    ....
    private final FieldNamingStrategy fieldNamingStrategy;

    public BasicMongoPersistentProperty(Field field, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, MongoPersistentEntity<?> owner, SimpleTypeHolder simpleTypeHolder, FieldNamingStrategy fieldNamingStrategy) {

      super(field, propertyDescriptor, owner, simpleTypeHolder);
      this.fieldNamingStrategy = fieldNamingStrategy == null ? PropertyNameFieldNamingStrategy.INSTANCE : fieldNamingStrategy;

      if (isIdProperty() && getFieldName() != ID_FIELD_NAME) {
        LOG.warn("Customizing field name for id property not allowed! Custom name will not be considered!");
      }
    }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is from the spring boot appendix

```
# MONGODB (MongoProperties)
spring.data.mongodb.field-naming-strategy= # Fully qualified name of the FieldNamingStrategy to use
```

You've got the follow strategies out of the box

```
CamelCaseSplittingFieldNamingStrategy
CamelCaseAbbreviatingFieldNamingStrategy
SnakeCaseFieldNamingStrategy
```

If these dont suit your needs, feel free to extend them

Comment: what trace? When I debug ,the final FieldNamingStrategy is always null, even if out of box ones or customized ones. And so , testing SnakeCaseFieldNamingStrategy inserting one, it didn't change,for examle, camelCase is still the same not camel_case

Comment: this is a relative question,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523125/how-to-set-mongodb-field-naming-strategy-in-spring-boot